# Conflict between wow slider and angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
<div  class="clearfix" id="image-block" ng-init="GetAllSingleProduct">
<div id="wowslider-container1" >
<div class="ws_images" ng-repeat="image in allSingleProduct"><ul>
<li><img ng-src="imagesT/data/images/{{image.imagename}}" alt="WIN_20150316_191218" title="WIN_20150316_191218" class=""/></li>
</ul></div>
<div class="ws_bullets"  ng-repeat="image in allSingleProduct"><div>
<a href="#" title="WIN_20150316_191218"><span><img ng-src="imagesT/data/tooltips/{{image.imagename}}" alt="WIN_20150316_191218"/>1</span></a>
</div></div><div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a href="http://wowslider.com">slider</a> by hasan</div>
<div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I run the site and open firebug this div `ws_images` does not appear. Can any body help?

Comment: i noticed that i forget the () in GetAllSingleProduct to be GetAllSingleProduct() and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

If your `div.ws_images` tag is not showing up, this means that your `allSingleProduct` array has no elements in it and `ng-repeat` is not looping through it.

Make sure `allSingleProduct` is not empty.